# Method being called constantly until the view is dismissed

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have an endGame view that loads when the user completes a game. It is presented modally over top of the game view. In viewDidLoad I am calling a method to save data such the score and how many of a certain game mode they have played. That method is being called multiple times - about once per second, but it is irregular.

**End Game Screen:**

```
#import "endGameScreen.h"
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "GameData.h"

@implementation endGameScreen

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

}

- (void)awakeFromNib {
    [self getAchievementData];
}

- (void)getAchievementData {
    [RWGameData sharedGameData].timedPlayed++;
    NSLog(@"Timed played: %ld", [RWGameData sharedGameData].timedPlayed);
}

- (void)writeAchievementforKey:(NSString *)achKey {
    [data setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:1] forKey:achKey];
    [data writeToFile: path atomically:YES];
}
```

I am loading the endGameScreen class like this:
**GameViewController.m**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    if (self.gameMode == 1) {
        self.gridSize = 3;
        secondsLeft = 10;
        [self countdownTimer];
    }
}

-(void)countdownTimer {
    secondsLeft = minutes = seconds = 0;
    timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0f target:self selector:@selector(updateCounter:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}

// Timer in the game going to zero
- (void)updateCounter:(NSTimer *)theTimer {
    if (secondsLeft > 0 ){
        secondsLeft -- ;
        minutes = (secondsLeft % 3600) / 60;
        seconds = (secondsLeft %3600) % 60;
        timePlayedLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02d:%02d", minutes, seconds];
        if (secondsLeft == 1) {
            //Call endGame method
            timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0
                                             target:self
                                           selector:@selector(endGame)
                                           userInfo:nil
                                            repeats:NO];
        }
    }
    else {
        secondsLeft = 10;
    }
}

- (void)endGame {
    [timer invalidate];
    [self saveScores];

    //Segue in the storyboard
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"endGame" sender:self];
}

-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"endGame"]) {
        endGameScreen *vc = [segue destinationViewController];
        if (self.gameMode == 1) {
            vc.gameMode = 1;
        }
        else {
            vc.gameMode = 2;
        }
    }
}
```

I am getting NSLog messages that continually increment saying "Mode One played: 27", "Mode One played: 28", "Mode One played: 29", and so on.

Comment: Hi, Are you sure you don't call this method somewhere else?

Comment: Please add some more code of your file this code doesn't describe your problem?

Comment: I have added more code from the endGameScreen class and have showed how I call it in the the gameViewController.

Comment: I am only calling the method in awakeFromNib. I have tried it in viewDidLoad to the same effect.

Comment: You don't show what posts `GameDataUpdatedFromiCloud`. You don't show the `-didUpdateGameData:` method. You don't show what calls `-updateCounter:`. I'm guessing the latter is called repeatedly, even after it has scheduled the timer to call `-endGame`, and so do *that* repeatedly.

Comment: I don't think those are relevant so I've removed those. I replaced everything in getAchievementData (the only method being called in endGameScreen) and it still repeats. Wouldn't the timer stop once it transitions to a new view? I have invalidated the timer on the segue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `-endGame` method isn't invalidating the timer you think it is.

`-updateCounter:` is overwriting your `timer` instance variable with the new one-shot timer for calling `-endGame`, but that doesn't stop the other timer, the one created in `-countdownTimer`. That timer continues to fire, calling `-updateCounter:`, which keeps creating more one-shot timers to call `-endGame`. So, that gets called repeatedly.